# linq to sql connection

Tags: linq-to-sql

i used following expression in my linq to sql connection.

```
       int before = db.Employees.Count();

        var after = (from c in db.Employees
                     where c.emp_city == "pune"
                     select c).Count;


        Console.WriteLine("# of Customers= {0}, In pune= {1}", before, after);


        Console.ReadLine();
```

it give this error:

Error   1   Cannot assign method group to an implicitly-typed local variable

how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

you forgot to actually call the Count method, add parentheses:

```
 var after = (from c in db.Employees
                 where c.emp_city == "pune"
                 select c).Count();
```